# how to solve exception class java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to class java.util.Enumeration in HashMap

Tags: java, exception, collections, enums, hashmap

I am getting the error in ClassCastException as below.

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap$Values
> cannot be cast to class java.util.Enumeration
> (java.util.HashMap$Values and java.util.Enumeration are in module
> java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> ```

```
public static void addMemberships(final int key, MembershipData[] members) throws SpiderException
  {
    HashMap duplicates = new HashMap();
    for (int i=0; i<members.length; i++)
    {
      if (duplicates.get(members[i].subjectOfCare) == null) {
        duplicates.put(members[i].subjectOfCare, members[i]);
      }
    }

    members = new MembershipData[duplicates.size()];
    Enumeration elements = (Enumeration) duplicates.values();    //line where error occurs

    for (int i=0; i<members.length; i++){
      members[i] = (MembershipData) elements.nextElement();      
    }

    internalMembershipToolkit.verifyData(key, members);
  }
```

I tried using `Enumeration elements =  new IteratorEnumeration(duplicates.keySet().iterator());` but then I get another `ClassCastException`. Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error actually occurs on this line: `numeration elements = (Enumeration) duplicates.values();`, not the one you pointed out in your source code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes error occurs in there. Thank you.

Comment: The `values` method returns a `Collection`. How would you expect to be able to cast it to an `Enumeration`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: And please don't rollback valid edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumeration` is an ancient interface that you should almost never need. It has been superseded by the Collection API, introduced in JDK 1.2, back-then in 1998.

When you use the capabilities of the Collection API, your entire code can be simplified to

```
public static void addMemberships(int key,MembershipData[] members) throws SpiderException
{
    HashMap<Object, MembershipData> duplicates = new HashMap<>();
    for(MembershipData m: members) duplicates.putIfAbsent(m.subjectOfCare, m);

    members = duplicates.values().toArray(new MembershipData[0]); 

    internalMembershipToolkit.verifyData(key, members);
}
```

Note that assigning a new array to the parameter variable `members` does not alter the caller’s array. You could also pass the new array directly to the `verifyData` call, like

```
internalMembershipToolkit.verifyData(key,
    duplicates.values().toArray(new MembershipData[0]));
```

More than often, you get even more advantages from the Collection API when eliminating the need to convert from and to an array. E.g. when you change the `verifyData` to accept a `Collection<MembershipData>` instead of `MembershipData[]`, you can simply pass the `duplicates.values()` to the method, without the need to copy it into a new array.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on the line:

```
Enumeration elements = (Enumeration) duplicates.values();    //line where error occurs
```

HashMap.values() returns a `Collection`, not an `Enumeration`. You can fix this like so:

```
Iterator elements = duplicates.values().iterator();    //line where error occurs
```

Comment: Tried using using answer. But then how can I change line --> members[i] = (MembershipData) elements.nextElement(); . nextElement() do not consist for iterator

Comment: @ShaviPathirana look at the API for Iterator. It is different but similar to Enumeration

Comment: You don’t need to deal with `Iterator` at all for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
Collection<MembershipData> elements = duplicates.values();
Iterator<MembershipData> itr = elements.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < members.length && itr.hasNext(); i++) {
    members[i] = itr.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but you are trying to iterate over HashMap values and put it's values in an array.
This can be easily achieved using generics. Define your Map as:

```
Map<Integer,MembershipData> duplicates = new HashMap<Integer,MembershipData>();
```

And then iterating it over like

```
i=0;
for(MembershipData data:dupliates.values()){
    members[i++] = data;
}
```